# Are finitely generated projective modules free over the total ring of fractions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $Q(A)$ be the total ring of fractions of a commutative reduced non-noetherian ring $A$. Let $P$ be a finitely generated projective module over $Q(A)$ which is of constant rank (i.e. locally free of constant rank for each localization). Is $P$ free?
(Note that $Q(A)$ need not be zero dimensional.)

Comment: dimension of a reduced von Neumann regular ring $A$ is 0, and f.g. projective modules of constant rank over zero dimensional ring are free. In general, if dimension of a commutative ring $A$ is $d$ ($A$ need not be noetherian), and $P$ is a f.g. projective $A$-module of constant rank $r>d$, then $P$ is isomorphic to $Q\oplus A$. This result is due to Heitmann (1982) and the Noetherian case of this result is due to Serre (1960).

Comment: $Q$ is some projective $A$-module of rank $r-1$. Basically it says that whenever rank of $P$ is $>$ dimension of $A$, then $P$ splits a free summand, i.e. there is an $A$-linear surjection from $P$ to $A$. This result is best possible, since there are counter-examples when $r=d$. Heitmann's paper is (1984) titled "Generating non-noetherian modules efficiently", Michigan J. of Math. For counter example, we can take a Dedekind domain which is not a PID. Then non-principle ideals are rank 1 projective modules, but not free.

Comment: For higher dimensional examples, we can take $A$ to be the coordinate ring of real sphere $S^n$ when $n\not=1,3,7$ and, i.e. $A=\mathbb R[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/(x_0^2+\ldots+x_n^2-1)$, and $P$ is the projective module which is $A^{n+1}/(x_0,\ldots,x_n)A$. Then $P\oplus A$ is free, but $P$ is not free. Further, when $n$ is even, there is no surjection from $P$ to $A$. In this case, note that rank of $P=$ dimension of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the beginning only few hints which led to the conclusion that the answer to your question is NO.

In [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207406/irreducible-components-of-the-prime-spectrum-of-a-quotient-ring-and-primary-deco) I've defined the idealization of a module. I'll repost the construction for the sake of completeness.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ an $R$-module. On the set $A=R\times M$ one defines the following two algebraic operations:

$$(a,x)+(b,y)=(a+b,x+y)$$

$$(a,x)(b,y)=(ab,ay+bx).$$

With these two operations $A$ becomes a commutative ring with $(1,0)$ as unit element. ($A$
is called the *idealization* of the $R$-module $M$ or the *trivial extension* of $R$ by $M$).

Remarks: if every noninvertible element of $R$ kill some nonzero element of $M$, then $A$ equals its own total ring of fractions. Such an example is the following: take $(\mathfrak m_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of maximal ideals of $R$ such that every noninvertible element of $R$ belong to an $\mathfrak m_i$ and set $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} R/\mathfrak m_i$.

Construction: take $R$ such that there exists a nonfree projective $R$-module of rank $1$. Now define $M$ as before in such a way that there exists a nonfree projective $A$-module of rank $1$.

**Edit.** Unfortunately I've forgot that the ring $A$ should be reduced. But an example for the reduced case can be found in Lam, *Exercises in Modules and Rings*, Exercise 2.35.

Comment: Havn't checked the details, but this looks nice !

Comment: This is a nice construction. But ring $A$ is not reduced as every element of $M$ is nilpotent in $A$. Further, $A/nil(A)=R/nil(R)$. If we do not require reduced ring, then this might work, since taking non-free projective $R$-module, say $P$ ,we can construct $Q=P\otimes_R A$. This will be projectiv $A$-module, and $Q$ can not be free, otherwise $Q/MQ=P$ will be free $R$-module.

Comment: @manoj Yeah, I've forgot that the ring must be reduced! I've edited my answer.

Comment: So what is the answer? Not everyone has the book by Lam.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sometimes google can help in such situations: see [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=LKMCTP4EecYC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=%22to+construct+a+reduced+ring+R+%22&source=bl&ots=8BryQTTViH&sig=Em9GqGSIktOHKFqugtcenlgKg90&hl=ro&sa=X&ei=EwcmUdGsAYLTswb-04DgBw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20construct%20a%20reduced%20ring%20R%20%22&f=true).

Comment: @YACP. Thanks for the reference. Congratulations! I do not know the dimension of the ring $R$ in Lam's exercise. Is it finite? I will be happy to get a finite dimensional ring $R$ with above properties.

Comment: We can take any domain $S$ s.t. f.g. non-free projective $S$-module $P$ exist. Then simple take $P\otimes_S R$. Since $S$ is a retract of $R$, $P\otimes_S R$ will be f.g. non-free projective $R$-module. Thanks again.

Comment: In the Lam's construction of ring $R$ (Ex. 2.34), $R$ is union of rings $S\subset S_1\subset S_2 \subset ...$ The dimension of $S_1$ is max $(1, dim S)$. From this I would like to conclude that dimension of $R$ is also max $(1,dim S)$.