# Any characterization for commutative rings over which "projective modules" equal "free modules"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

As far as I know, over any PID, an polynomial rings over a field, or an local ring, projective modules are always free.

> This kind of results make me curious about if there are any overall characterization of a commutative ring $R$ such that all projective $R$-modules are free.

Does anyone have some thoughts on it? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely not: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115187/condition-for-a-ring-on-projective-and-free-modules-problem

Comment: @user26857  Thank for offering the link. Seems that such a characterization is extremely unachievable.